# Recursive computation using Piecewise

Tags: matrix, recursion, debugging

I am trying to create an array using a series of equations using `Piecewise`. I am stuck in one of them. I am just putting a simplified version of code as below.

I am trying build a table `d` using variable `fd` which calculates value using equation

```
fd[i,j]= Max[s[i]-strike1,0]
```

using value from another table `s` based on equation when `j = ts + 1`.

When I run the function the first time using `recursive[5, 4, 5, 10]` it gives the right value.

However if I change the parameter and run it a second time e.g. `recursive[5, 4, 4, 6]`, somehow `fd` is remembering the first iteration.

How can I remove value from previous iteration?

```
recursive[as_, ts_, ds_, strike1_] := 
 Module[{s, d}, s = Table[i*ds, {i, 0, as + 1}]; 
  fd[i_, j_] := Piecewise[{{Max[s[[i]] - strike1, 0], j == ts + 1}}];
  d = Table[fd[i, j], {i, 1, as + 2}, {j, 1, ts + 1}];
  Grid[d]
  ]
```

Comment: If you have not done so since your last question, restart *Mathematica*. You had an incorrect memoization in your previous code which could cause this problem.

Comment: I can solve this issue by executing Clear[fd]. However I am running into problem when I add additional condition in Piecewise like. I want to add second condition where fd[I, j] will be for  1 < i < as + 2 and  j < ts + 1  and and hence added this one{(fd[i + 1, j - 1] - fd[i - 1, j - 1])/ds, 
 1 < i < as + 2 && j < ts + 1}

Comment: i am 1000 of errors and mathematica hangs

Comment: Please take a look at the [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) for new Mathematica.SE users, and [in particular take a look at how to format your code](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Comment: The actual code in your question seems to work fine, with reversing the order of `recursive[5, 4, 5, 10]` and `recursive[5, 4, 4, 6]` having no adverse effect.  If you wish readers to comment on the effect of a second condition, please add the revised code to your question, so that we can see and evaluate it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem cannot be reproduced